# PyDev Magic Methods Auto-Complete

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, pycharm

How do i make PyDev auto-complete magic methods in a class.

In PyCharm, for example, Whenever I start typing "def" in a class I get suggestions like:
"**add**"  and  "**cmp**".

[PyCharm](http://snag.gy/L4RCH.jpg)

I tried looking for answers on the web and on forums but no one knows the answer.
How do i make this work in PyDev?
Thanks.

Comment: i'm used to eclipse and this should be working in PyDev also.

Comment: what makes you think that?

Comment: do you know for a fact that it can't be done? maybe adding external libraries or something

Comment: well, PyDev is open-source, so this can be done: you can modify the source code of PyDev to add this feature.